# bixby use audio in quiz example

Tags: javascript, samsung-mobile, bixby

I am trying to modify [quiz example](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-quiz) for Bixby to make it work with audio player. 
I want to build basic "Guess the Song Game Quiz" and I want to play audio after prompt. But I stuck with the logic of Bixby. And not sure what structure of models should I use.

I added `PlayAudio.model.bxb` to models:

```
action (PlayAudio) {
  description (plays audio of quiz)
  type (Calculation)
  collect {
    input (quiz) {
      type (Quiz)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }

    computed-input (quiz.audioToPlay) {
      description (By passing in the AudioInfo object to the PlayAudio action, we ask the client to play our sound.)
      type (audioPlayer.Result)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: audioPlayer.PlayAudio
          value: $expr(quiz.audioToPlay)
        }
      }
      hidden
    }
  }
  output (Quiz)
}
```

and changed the start `UpdateQuiz.model.bxb`:

```
action (UpdateQuiz) {
  type (Search)
  description (Compares the user's answer to the correct answer and updates your score and move to the next question)
  collect {
    input (answer) {
      type (Answer)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (quiz) {
      type (Quiz)
      min (Required) max (One)
      validate {
       if (quiz.audioToPlay != null) {
        replan {
          intent {
            goal: PlayAudio
            value { $expr(quiz) }
          }
        }
        }           
       }
      }
    }
  output (Quiz)
}
```

It plays audio after user answer but not after Bixby question. I understand that I added audio intent as part of answer validation and validation will be executed after answer but i am not sure how to make it play audio correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure the `if (quiz.audioToPlay != null)` is the correct syntax, it may or may not work as you intended. You should use `if (exists(quiz.audioToPlay))`. You can find more example about **validate** [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input.validate)

Second, it also might be the case that quiz.audioToPlay is not not constructed correctly. You can verify the content by make sure it plays using a simple action.

You can also reach us by using the **contact support** in IDE.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will try to contact the support. it plays the sound. but plays it in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

T play audio just after question I changed `UpdateQuiz` model.

```
action (UpdateQuiz) {
  type (Search)
  description (Compares the user's answer to the correct answer and updates your score and move to the next question)
  collect {

    input (quiz) {
      type (Quiz)
      min (Required) max (One)
      validate {
       if (exists(quiz.audioToPlay) && !quiz.completed) {
        replan {
          intent {
            //goal: UpdateQuiz
            goal: PlayAudio
            value { $expr(quiz) }
          }
        }
        }           
       }
      }

      input (answer) {
      type (Answer)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    }
  output (Quiz)
}
```